# How do I increment integers inside foreach and statement?

Tags: c#, foreach, increment, post-increment

How can I increment an integer inside a foreach loop (like in C++)

This is my code, but it does not increment the `selectIndex` integer during each loop iteration.

```
var list = new List<string>();
int selectIndex = 0;

foreach(TType t in Gls.TTypes)
{
    selectIndex = Gls.TType.Name == t.Name ? selectIndex++ : 0;
    list.Add(t.Name);
}
```

Got it working as follows:

```
var list = new List<string>();
int selectIndex = 0;
int counter = 0;
foreach(TaxType t in Globals.TaxTypes)
{
    selectIndex = Globals.TaxType.Name == t.Name ? counter : selectIndex;
    counter++;

    list.Add(t.Name);
}
```

The purpose was to select the matching item in a UIPickerView.

Many thanks to all contributions!

Comment: what's wrong with `if(Gls.TType.Name == t.Name) selectIndex++; else selectIndex = 0;`?

Comment: Can you show your working C++ equivalent? Seems like we're having trouble figuring out what you're trying to do.

Comment: `list.Count` would have completely replaced the need for `counter`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IMHO that pattern you are using here is horrid.  Pre and postfix increments modify the value they're invoked upon so it makes no sense to then copy the result (incidentally it's not working because you're copying the value before the postfix increment takes place).

So you can use solutions like @Vilx- and @KarthikT's - but in my opinion, instead of trying to cram it all on one line I'd much rather see:

```
if(Gls.TType.Name == t.Name) 
  selectIndex++;
else selectIndex = 0;
```

Don't get me wrong - I use the conditional operator a lot; but I wouldn't in this case.

Comment: I agree! I am very fond of shorthand, too much in fact!

Comment: Marked as correct since your comments are that led me to the solution.

Answer (score 3):

does you mean

```
selectIndex += (Gls.TType.Name == t.Name ? 1 : 0);
```

?

if you want to find an index of object whose name equals Gls.TType.Name, then the following code helps you.

```
var list = new List<string>();
foreach(TaxType t in Globals.TaxTypes)
{
    list.Add(t.Name);
}
int selectIndex = list.FindIndex(t => t == Globals.TaxTypes.Name);
```

Comment: Interesting, but no, since after after a true, it keeps incrementing again.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose you're looking for the right syntax... I suppose you just made a bug with the

```
foreach(TType t in Gls.TTypes)
{
     selectIndex += (Gls.TType.Name == t.Name) ? 1 : 0;
     list.Add(t.Name);
}
```

or

```
foreach(TType t in Gls.TTypes)
{
     selectIndex = (Gls.TType.Name == t.Name) ? selectIndex+1 : selectIndex;
     list.Add(t.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I like use scopes in situations if I need some kind of variable to increment.
Variable will only exist in scope, so it will be same as in for cycle. Garbage collector will destroy it after all.(prob would be better do something with using but Iam not guru at this lang.)

```
{
    int index = 6;
    foreach (var item in obj)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.text+index);
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped to well get my result.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `selectIndex = selectIndex++`, I expect you would increment, and immediately after that reset it to the old value.. ( since post-increment operator returns value before increment)

I would suggest a simple `selectIndex = selectIndex + 1` instead of the as functional but unnecessary `++selectIndex`

The modified statement would be -

```
selectIndex = Gls.TType.Name == t.Name ? selectIndex+1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Write it like this:

```
selectIndex = Gls.TType.Name == t.Name ? selectIndex+1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this `selectIndex = Gls.TType.Name == t.Name ? ++selectIndex : 0;`

See here : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for how `++` operator works